# Ruby runt precision error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm using the [runt](https://github.com/texel/runt) gem in a rails 3 upgrade (ruby 1.9.3), and get this error: `undefined method`precision' for nil:NilClass`.

This is how to replicate it on irb/pry:

```
> require 'runt'
=> true
> start_at = Runt::PDate.min(2009,1,1, 0, 0)
=> #<Runt::PDate: 2009-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2454833j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
> end_at = Runt::PDate.min(2009,1,1, 1, 30)
=> #<Runt::PDate: 2009-01-01T01:30:00+00:00 ((2454833j,5400s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
> runt_pattern = Runt::EveryTE.new(start_at, 600)
=> every 600 minutes starting Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 2009
> date_range = Runt::DateRange.new(start_at, end_at)
=> #<Runt::PDate: 2009-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2454833j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
..
#<Runt::PDate: 2009-01-01T01:30:00+00:00 ((2454833j,5400s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
> schedule = Runt::Schedule.new
=> #<Runt::Schedule:0x007fd46cad56b8 @elems={}>
> schedule.add 'events', runt_pattern
=> every 600 minutes starting Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 2009
> schedule.dates('events', date_range)
NoMethodError: undefined method `precision' for nil:NilClass
from /Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/runt-0.7.0/lib/runt/dprecision.rb:121:in `<=>'
```

Does anyone know anything about this?

It seems to be be triggered by this line: https://github.com/texel/runt/blob/master/lib/runt/schedule.rb#L28, but still trying to figure out how to dig further into the code.

I've noticed that there are some more updated runt versions, such as https://github.com/craigw/runt, but they don't seem to fix the problem either.

It works on rails2 on ree-1.8.7-2011.03, and returns `[Thu, 01 Jan 2009 00:00:00 +0000]`.

Edit: Added what rails2 returns.

Comment: Being that it works on rails 2, and that it is probably using activesupport.  So I would imagine there is an incompatibility with activesupport for rails 3. as the code you sent is 4 years old.

Comment: Is there a place that shows what has changed? I'm thinking it might be more a ruby 1.8.7 to ruby 1.9.3 issue, as I found another one of those in this library.

Comment: It works for ruby 1.9.2p290 - must be something that changed going to ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your problem is in the [EveryTE class](https://github.com/texel/runt/blob/master/lib/runt/temporalexpression.rb).  In the initialize method there is an optional precision parameter.

```
class EveryTE

  include TExpr

  def initialize(start,n,precision=nil)
    @start=start
    @interval=n
    # Use the precision of the start date by default
    @precision=precision || @start.date_precision
  end

  def include?(date)
    i=DPrecision.to_p(@start,@precision)
    d=DPrecision.to_p(date,@precision)
    while i<=d
      return true if i.eql?(d)
      i=i+@interval
    end
    false
  end

  def to_s
    "every #{@interval} #{@precision.label.downcase}s starting #{Runt.format_date(@start)}"
  end

end
```

I would try to supply a precision rather than accepting the default nil.

```
> runt_pattern = Runt::EveryTE.new(start_at, 600,Runt::DPrecision::Precision.sec)
```

Here is the full list of precisions (in [DPrecision class](https://github.com/texel/runt/blob/master/lib/runt/dprecision.rb)):

```
Precision.year
Precision.month
Precision.week
Precision.day
Precision.hour
Precision.min
Precision.sec
Precision.millisec
```

Comment: I tried this, and got the same error. Also `@precision` would equal `start_at.precision` (DPrecision::MINUTE) on this line: https://github.com/texel/runt/blob/master/lib/runt/temporalexpression.rb#L686, so it wouldn't be nil in this case.

Comment: Also, for reference, and to test it in the console, you would use `runt_pattern = Runt::EveryTE.new(start_at, 600, Runt::DPrecision::Precision.min)`